# Removing "snap to column" in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, scrolling

I have a column in Excel 2007 whose width is set to 200. This means that it is longer than the width of my screen. If I scroll the worksheet from left to right, it will move column by column, which means that I can only view part of the long column. How do I change this such that it doesn't "snap to column" and I can scroll the worksheet freely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, at least not in any version of Excel I've seen.  The left hand side starts with a column's left margin, and that's it.

A couple of options you do have:

- Decrease the width of the column, add wrapping to any cells that go beyond the edge of the cell and view the contents in a multi-line format. This is probably how you want to provide an output version (eg, printed report, spreadsheet fragment for a word doc, powerpoint presentation etc) in any event
- Use <Ctrl-Mouse wheel> to zoom in and out of your spreadsheet. This might make it difficult to read the contents of the too-wide column in zoomed-out mode, but you will see how the overall sheet looks.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have no choice but to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Select All > Resize one column

This will apply the same size to all columns, so if you shrink all the columns, one column won't be dominating the view anymore.

I was looking for this too because I had one column that was automatically sized on import, and it was bigger than the view, and I couldn't shrink it without going into the column properties.